# Is it possible to open an Qt resource using C library functions via FILE*?

Tags: c++, qt, qresource

I need to pass a binary resource that's compiled into my executable to some code that expects a file path, and then uses the C standard library `FILE*`-based API to access it.

Of course if I pass a path recognized by Qt, like `:/something.smt` - it won't work, because that's not visible directly to the C library.

Is there a way to bridge the two?

Comment: I don't think this is possible to do it directly. I believe you first need to extract the resource to a file.

Comment: Not without doing extra work, and not portably. But you can of course make this bridge, in an implementation-specific way for every C library: glibc, the one on Windows, and the one on macOS. That will cover all major platforms. So: you can do it, but you have to write some code to do it.

Comment: This is a decent question: it wasn't worded perfectly, but who would think that it was *unclear*? It's perfectly clear, and a common issue with various framework-specific virtual file systems. GTK users face the same issue, so doe those who use wxWindows, etc.

Comment: Under GLIBC, it's possible - see `fopencookie(3)`. But I'm not sure of the details.